# (Angular 4 + firebase + service + component) pass variable from service to component

Tags: angular, firebase, service, components, angularfire

I want to send variable "**dataJSONparse**" from service to component

**Service**

```
listOfUsers() {
this.items = <FirebaseListObservable<any>>this.af.list('/user', {
    query: {
    orderByChild: 'name'
    }
}).map((user) => {
    return user.map(user_data => {
    user_data.name;
    user_data.mobile;
    return user_data;
    })
})

    this.userDataQuery = this.items.subscribe(x => this.forx(x));
}

public dataJSONparse: any;
forx(x) {
    this.dataStringify = JSON.stringify(x);
    this.dataJSONparse = JSON.parse(this.dataStringify);
    console.log("test print from service: ",this.dataJSONparse);
}
```

**Component**

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("test",this.heroservice.dataJSONparse);
  }
```

**Console Error**

> test from component undefined
>
> test print from service:  Array [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object ]

[Error print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwqSO.png)

Comment: You should return an observable to your component. Even in your logging, you can see that the component console is printed before the service, which means that it's executed first and being therefore undefined :) Welcome to the asynchronous world :D

Comment: @AJT_82 
what can i do to solve it ?? if you have good tutorial to help me please post it in comment :)